# The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-time: How much does Mrs Alexander know?

Tags: character-analysis, curious-incident-dog-in-night-time, mark-haddon

In The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-time one of the characters, Mrs Alexander, reveals to Christopher that his mother and Mr Shears were having an affair. Later, however, she seems surprised when Christopher reveals that his mother isn't, in fact, dead.

If she was aware of such an intimate detail such as the affair I'd imagine she would also know Christopher's mother was still alive or at least expect to have heard of her death. Is this over-sight on the writer's part or is there something I missed in the story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mrs Alexander knew about Christopher's mother's affair, but not about her 'death'.**

In the same conversation when she tells Christopher about the affair, he tells her that his mother died. She was shocked to hear this, but she took Christopher's word for it. Perhaps she'd known her neighbours well enough to know about the affair (or perhaps she'd heard about that through gossip from *other* neighbours who knew them better), but she probably assumed that Christopher's mother had gone away with Mr Shears and she simply hadn't heard about her death. Perhaps the affair was common knowledge in the neighbourhood, and Mrs Alexander assumed that the death was something less talked about (scandal always makes for better gossip than tragedy).

After all, if the lie about Christopher's mother's death was good enough to fool Christopher himself - her own son, and a boy with a shrewd and enquiring mind - surely it can't have been something that a neighbour who didn't know the family very well could have seen through.

> Then  she  sucked  in  another  big  breath  and  said,  “Because...  because  I  think  you  know  why your father doesn’t like Mr. Shears very much.”
>   Then I asked, “Did Mr. Shears kill Mother?”
>   And Mrs. Alexander said, “Kill her?”
>   And I said, “Yes. Did he kill Mother?”
>   And Mrs. Alexander said, “No. No. Of course he didn’t kill your mother.”
>   And I said, “But did he give her stress so that she died of a heart attack?”
>   And Mrs. Alexander said, “I honestly don’t know what you’re talking about, Christopher.”
>   And I said, “Or did he hurt her so that she had to go into hospital?”
>   And Mrs. Alexander said, “Did she have to go into hospital?”
>   And I said, “Yes. And it wasn’t very serious at first, but she had a heart attack when she was in hospital.”
>   And Mrs. Alexander said, “Oh my goodness.”
>   **I said, “And she died.”**
>   **And Mrs. Alexander said “Oh my goodness” again, and then she said, “Oh, Christopher, I am so, so sorry. I never realized.”**
>   Then  I  asked  her,  “Why  did  you  say  ‘I  think  you  know  why  your  father  doesn’t  like  Mr. Shears very much’?”
>   Mrs.  Alexander  put  her hand  over  her  mouth and  said, “Oh  dear,  dear,  dear.”  But  she  didn’t answer my question.
>   So  I  asked  her  the  same  question  again,  because  in a  murder  mystery  novel  when  someone doesn’t  want  to  answer  a  question  it  is  because  they  are  trying  to  keep  a  secret  or  trying  to  stop someone  from  getting  into  trouble,  which  means  that  the  answers  to  those  questions  are  the  most important answers of all, and that is why the detective has to put that person under pressure.
>   But  Mrs.  Alexander  still  didn’t  answer.  Instead  she  asked  me  a  question.  She  said,  “So  you don’t know?”
>   And I said, “Don’t know what?”
>
> [...]
>
> And  she  said,  “I  shouldn’t  have  said  what  I  said.  And  if  I  don’t  explain,  you’ll  carry  on wondering what I meant. And you might ask your father. And I don’t want you to do that because I don’t  want  you  to  upset him.  So  I’m  going  to  explain  why  I  said  what  I said.  But  before  I  do  that you have to promise not to tell anyone I said this to you.”
>   I asked, “Why?”
>   And she said, “Christopher, please, just trust me.”
>   And  I  said,  “I  promise.”  Because  if  Mrs.  Alexander told  me  who  killed  Wellington,  or  she told me that Mr. Shears had really killed Mother, I could still go to the police and tell them because you are allowed to break a promise if someone has committed a crime and you know about it.
>   **And  Mrs.  Alexander  said,  “Your  mother,  before  she  died,  was  very  good  friends  with  Mr. Shears.”**
>   And I said, “I know.”
>   And  she  said,  “No,  Christopher.  I’m  not  sure  that  you  do.  I  mean  that  they  were  very  good friends. Very, very good friends.”
>   I thought about this for a while and said, “Do you mean that they were doing sex?”
>   And Mrs. Alexander said, “Yes, Christopher. That is what I mean.”
>
> <sub>-- Chapter '97' (emphasis mine)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Mrs Alexander heard that Mr. Shears was good friends with Christopher’s mother. She thinks that Christopher’s mother passed away because Christopher’s father lied to his son and Christopher told that lie he heard from his father to Mrs. Alexander